# How can i insert xml data from exec sp_name in to a dynamic table?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want ot do this how can I?

```
Insert into #DynamicTable values(exec mysp @Temp)
```

Here mysp returning xml data using for xml raw in mysp.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Insert Values of Stored Procedure in Table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/23/sql-server-insert-values-of-stored-procedure-in-table-use-table-valued-function/)